# Query for Counting Values Which are not entered in Column in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
School_ID char(3), 
St_LastName char(15), 
St_FirstName char(15), 
St_DOB char(15), 
St_SS# char(15), 
St_Address char(15),
St_City char(15), 
St_State char(2),
st_Zip char(5), 
st_phone char(15)
);
```

I have to write the query: **Determine how many students do not have a phone.**

I have write the following query in ACCESS

```
SELECT STUDENT.School_ID
FROM STUDENT
WHERE STUDENT.st_phone NOT IN( SELECT STUDENT.st_phone, Count(STUDENT.st_phone) AS StudentWithNoPhone FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY STUDENT.st_phone);
```

but it's not working.

Comment: If a student has more two st_phone values will they have two records in student?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STUDENT.School_ID
FROM STUDENT
WHERE STUDENT.st_phone IS NULL OR STUDENT.st_phone = ''
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: And if the OP does want a count, it is easy enough to turn your query into one.

Comment: I think it's `COUNT(STUDENT.School_ID)` since the question asks *Determine how many students* but otherwise it's correct

Comment: its not working..Query should count the occorunces which are not entered in st_phone

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a COUNT that's wanted, but the query just pulls single ID's, so I wasn't sure. Either way....

Comment: @UsmanShafiArain did you add the alias `COUNT(STUDENT.School_ID) as CountOfSudentsWithNoPhones` that I forgot to mention

Comment: @ConradFrix i have tried it also ..but its returning no count

Comment: What does it return? 0? Or something else?

Comment: @UsmanShafiArain Please update your question with sample data and desired output.  No one can help with "its not working"